# Python script output to console doesn't update beyond first page in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

I'm debugging a python script that includes a Print statement. I'm running the script from the QGIS python editor and expecting to see output in the QGIS python console, however once the script has filled the console window rather than scrolling up with each print statement the console window no longer updates and I have to wait until the script has finished before I can see the output of my Print statements. Is there a way I can make the console scroll with each Print statement so I can see the output of the statements as they are processed rather than having to wait until the end.

I'm using QGIS 3.4.12 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

You generally shouldn't use `print()` for debugging this as the Python Console is not built to really help you here.

The best advice is to use `QgsMessageLog.logMessage` as that will scroll with the output and log out into the log window (bottom right button in the status bar)